# How to get rid of trailing string after using Convert?

Tags: conversion

```
Convert[0.05263, Percent] /. Percent -> "%"
```

I would like to remove the trailing "%" but if I put Percent->"" it concatenates a literal empty pair of quotes.

Thanks.

Edit: I should have explained it works well in the Mathematica interactive evaluator but not in an InputField where it will concatenate the said quotes.

Comment: `Convert` does not appear to be a built-in Mathematica function.  Are you using a package where `Convert` is defined?

Comment: Perhaps pre-9 Units package?

Comment: Yes I am using Units. So my code has a Needs["Units`"].  I am using Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 4):

For the older `` "Units`" `` package units are just symbols which are multiplied to numbers. If you want to get rid of them, just replace them with `1`:

```
 Convert[0.05263, Percent] /. Percent -> 1
```

In such cases, it is often very useful to use `InputForm` or even `FullForm` to explicitly check with what you are dealing and what is returned, e.g.:

```
 Convert[0.05263, Percent] /. Percent -> 1 // FullForm
```

which shows that now the number is all that's left, without any spurious relicts of the former units caculation...

Answer (score 0):

You can the following to check the `FullForm`  of your code (makes it easy to understand how Mathematica's internal structures works. Check Mathematica's reference if you want to know details about this.

```
FullForm[Convert[0.05263, Percent]]
(* Result: Times[5.263`,Percent] *)
```

There you see that it is a simple multiplication (Head: `Times`) of two elements. Then you can either use Albert Retey's solution or do a simple

```
First[Convert[0.05263, Percent]]
(* Result: 5.263 *)
```

This is especially usefull if you have a more complex output like

```
FullForm[SpeedOfLight]
(* Result: Times[299792458,Meter,Power[Second,-1]] *)
```

Then you can do a quick

```
First[SpeedOfLight]
(* Result: 299792458 *)
```

to get the value of this expression without the units.